# Calling a C function from C#. How to translate C prototype to C#?

Tags: c#, c, dll

I have a C function in a DLL that I want to call from my C# program:

```
void FindMinMax(double *values, int32_t i1, int32_t i2, double *minValue, double *maxValue);
```

I try to add the ability to call this function from my C# program

```
[DllImport("libFastFindMinMax.dll")]
        static private unsafe extern void FindMinMax(double[] values, Int32 i1, Int32 i2, out double minValue, out double maxValue);
```

This is way wrong I suppose (it does not work).

Where can I read how to translate a C prototype to C#?

How should a C function prototype look to be able to receive a double[] and use out parameters?

Comment: I think I have solved it:[DllImport("libFastFindMinMax.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static private unsafe extern void FindMinMax(double[] values, Int32 i1, Int32 i2, out double minValue, out double maxValue);

Comment: looks right to me, and if it works; that's most of the battle :)